# Start two wikijs containers with one docker-compose.yml and seperate database (postgres) through traefik

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, ubuntu-18.04, traefik

I am trying to start two wikijs containers with different databases through traefik. I have no problem in starting the containers. I can start traefik on a subdomain and I even can start the two wikis on different subdomains. My problem is the following: Every time I start the wikijs containers I always somehow use the same database and I don't know how to change that.

The purpose is, that I have customers which want to have a seperate wiki for their documentation. So I want to start as many wikijs containers as possible but preferably through one docker-compose.yml file.

Can anybody tell me, what I am doing wrong? Thanks = )

this is my traefik.toml file:

```
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
    address = ":80"
      [entryPoints.http.redirect]
        entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
    address = ":443"
      [entryPoints.https.tls]
  [entryPoints.dashboard]
    address = ":8080"
    [entryPoints.dashboard.auth]
      [entryPoints.dashboard.auth.basic]
        users = ["admin:$apr1$Ld55R9Cl$/8W5BCc.J/Qtg9Xtpk4lq0"]

[api]
entrypoint="dashboard"

[acme]
email = "email@domain.com" 
storage = "acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
onHostRule = true
  [acme.httpChallenge]
```

this is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
services:

  db:
    image: postgres:11-alpine
    networks:
      - internal
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=false"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: wiki1
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: wikijsrocks
      POSTGRES_USER: wikijs

    logging:
      driver: "none"
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  db1:
    image: postgres:11-alpine
    networks:
      - internal
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=false"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: wiki2
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: wikijsrocks
      POSTGRES_USER: wikijs

    logging:
      driver: "none"
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - db-data1:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  wiki1:
    image: requarks/wiki:2
    networks:
      - internal
      - web
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.backend=wiki1"
      - "traefik.docker.network=web"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:domain.com"
      - "traefik.http.services.wiki.loadbalancer.server.port=3000"

    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      DB_TYPE: postgres
      DB_HOST: db
      DB_PORT: 5432
      DB_USER: wikijs
      DB_PASS: wikijsrocks
      DB_NAME: wiki
    restart: unless-stopped

  wiki2:
    image: requarks/wiki:2
    networks:
      - internal
      - web
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.backend=wiki2"
      - "traefik.docker.network=web"
 - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:domain.com"                                                                                                                                                                                        - "traefik.http.services.wiki.loadbalancer.server.port=3000"

    depends_on:
      - db1
    environment:
      DB_TYPE: postgres
      DB_HOST: db1
      DB_PORT: 5432
      DB_USER: wikijs
      DB_PASS: wikijsrocks
      DB_NAME: wikispiral
    restart: unless-stopped

  adminer:
    image: adminer:4.6.3-standalone
    labels:
      - traefik.backend=adminer
      - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:domain.com
      - traefik.docker.network=web
      - traefik.port=8080
    networks:
      - internal
      - web
    depends_on:
      - db
      - db1
volumes:
  db-data:
  db-data1:
networks:
  web:
    external: true
internal:
    external: false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both databases are on the same network:

```
networks:
      - internal
```

and listening on the same port:

```
DB_PORT: 5432
```

So put each database in it's own network and add that network to the wikis service or instead change the port that one of them is listening to.

Comment: thank you very much! I got it to work after I used a different network for each db and wikijs. I also setup different volumes and left it on the same port. now it works = )

Comment: Please always remember to upvote and/or mark as accepted the answers that helped/resolved your issue.